# Grub Rescue command ls says failed reading section 0x0 from cd0

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I had Ubuntu 12.* installed on my system. Then I tried installing Windows8, which failed.
After starting my system I am getting Grub Rescue''

I did `ls`
output:`(cd0)`

then  `ls (cd0)`
output: `failed reading section 0x0 from cd0`

Other options says `unknown filesystem`